# How to format a CURRENCY type field in a datatable in LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforcedx, lwc-dom

How to format a CURRENCY type field (named "Amount") in a datatable so that there are only 2 digits at the end of the number after the dot (in the fractional part)? The table displays an object received from salesforce via apex in lwc.

description of columns in js file:

```
...
const COLUMNS_FOR_ACC = [
    {
        label: 'View',
        type: 'button-icon',
        initialWidth: 75,
        typeAttributes: {
            iconName: 'action:preview',
            title: 'Detail',
            variant: 'border-filled',
            alternativeText: 'View'
        }
    },
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true },

    //Problem field below
    { label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'Amount', type: 'Currency', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true },
    { label: 'CreatedDate', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true, typeAttributes:{day:'numeric',month:'short',year:'numeric',
    hour:'2-digit',minute:'2-digit',second:'2-digit',hour12:true}},
    { label: 'CloseDate', fieldName: 'CloseDate', type: 'date', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true }
];

...

export default class AccordionEx extends LightningElement
{
    columnsForAcc=COLUMNS_FOR_ACC;
    
...
```

using datatable in html file:

```
...
<lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open={multiple}>
        <template if:true={accountsOnThisPage}>
            <template for:each={accountsOnThisPage} for:item="acc">
                <lightning-accordion-section name={acc.Name} label={acc.ServiceText__c} key={acc.Id}>
                    <!-- The table is here -->
                    <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={acc.Opportunities} columns={columnsForAcc} onrowaction={handleRowAction} hide-checkbox-column="true" ></lightning-datatable>
                </lightning-accordion-section>
            </template>
        </template>
    </lightning-accordion>
...
```

This is what I get as a result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) `currency` field displays a currency using [lightning-formatted-number](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-number/specification), so you can set `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` properties to the `typeAttributes` object.
I.E. `typeAttributes: { minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }`

By the way, `type: 'Currency'` is wrong. It's `type: 'currency'`. Javascript is case sensitive. I updated the code below.

```js
const COLUMNS_FOR_ACC = [
    {
        label: 'View',
        type: 'button-icon',
        initialWidth: 75,
        typeAttributes: {
            iconName: 'action:preview',
            title: 'Detail',
            variant: 'border-filled',
            alternativeText: 'View'
        }
    },
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true },
    { label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'Amount', type: 'currency', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true, typeAttributes: { minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 2 } },
    { label: 'CreatedDate', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true, typeAttributes:{day:'numeric',month:'short',year:'numeric',
    hour:'2-digit',minute:'2-digit',second:'2-digit',hour12:true}},
    { label: 'CloseDate', fieldName: 'CloseDate', type: 'date', wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true }
];
```

Comment: I tried to set the values of the properties in different ways (in 0 and 2, including at the same time), tried to use only one property - nothing helps.

Comment: @PavelK I've updated the answer

Comment: You're right, it works, thanks